# How vCores and Memory get allocated from Spark Pool

Tags: azure-synapse

I have below spark pool config. Nodes : 3 to 10.

[image]

Spark Job config:

[image]

After seeing below allocation, looks like it is using all 10 nodes from the pool. 10 x 8 vCores = 80 vCores; 10 x 64 GB = 640 GB

BUT, I have set number of executors - min & max to 4 to 6. So, shouldn’t it go max to 6 x 8 vCores and 6 x 64 GB ? Please correct if I am missing something here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting confused between Spark Pool Allocated vCores, memory and Spark Job executor size which are two different things.

You have created a `ContractsMed` Spark Pool, which has max. 10 nodes with each node size equal to 8 vCores and 64 GB memory. That's the reason the last snippet you have shared containing Spark Pool Allocated vCores and Memory and not Spark Job details. So, 80 vCores and 640 GB is the Spark Pool size and not Spark Job

[image]

Now coming to Spark Job Configuration, where you are using `ContractsMed` Spark Pool. As you have configured maximum 6 executors with 8 vCores and 56 GB memory each, the same resources, i.e, 6x8=56 vCores and 6x56=336 GB memory will be fetched from the Spark Pool and used in the Job.

The remaining resources (80-56=24 vCores and 640-336=304 GB memory) from Spark Pool will remain unused and can be used in any other Spark Job.